# Incorrect background in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a game in `pygame`. I have Python 3.6 installed in Ubuntu, and this is how my code looks:

```py
import pygame
    
pygame.init()
   
# on_screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([800, 600])
pygame.display.set_caption('Little UFO')

# actors
ufo = pygame.image.load('ufo.png')

def player():
    screen.blit(ufo, (375, 591))

run = True
while run:
    screen.fill([255,255,255])
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        print(event)
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    player()
```

When I run it I see a black background even though I have selected white, and I can't see the ufo.

Comment: You need to properly indent your code. Currently, this code will not work due to the errors in indentations.

Comment: I have checked it is intended correctly

Comment: Try it again. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) is a formatting tutorial for SO. Try wrapping the code in triple backticks, they look like this: \`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `pygame.display.flip()` after drawing to the screen for changes to become visible.

By default, whenever drawing to your surface it actually draws to a hidden surface. Whenever you are done drawing everything on a frame you `flip` the front buffers with the back buffer. This way a user can never see a half-drawn screen.

Comment: I will try it for sure and share the results could you please explain me what that function does please

Comment: I have edited the answer to include a quick explanation. Look up double buffering if you want to know more

Comment: Thank you for that

Answer (score 0):

Add pygame.display.update() after the player function is called:

```
while run:
    screen.fill([255,255,255])
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        print(event)
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    player()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Using pygame.display.update() can be more efficient than flip() if you specify which section of the screen to update, more on that here: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update
If you don't pass any parameters it does the same job as pygame.display.flip()